# Remote Control Desktop via Firefox

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, firefox

I have a Windows 7 PC that I would like to remote control the desktop of using Firefox 28 (running on Windows XP) across the internet. Is there anything that makes this possible? The Windows XP machine I have limited control of so can not install thick client software.

Ideally the solution would also allow remote control from Android devices.

Comment: How limited is your installation abilities? Also have you tried teh build in Windows Remote Desktop?

Comment: Is a Chrome viewer ok? (http://www.realvnc.com/products/chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/):

- free
- supports Windows
- contains a [Web server](http://www.tightvnc.com/winst.php#start_java)

> Using a Web Browser as a Viewer
>
> The VNC servers also contain a small Web server. If you connect to it
>   with a web browser, the Java version of the viewer will be downloaded
>   automatically, allowing you to access the remote desktop. Obviously,
>   your Web browser must support Java applets. Also, you should not use a
>   proxy, to let the Java applet access the remote server directly.
>
> The server listens for HTTP connections on port 5800 + display number.
>   (Remember a WinVNC machine defaults to the display 0.) So to connect
>   to the display 2 on machine "myhost", you would point your web browser
>   at: `http://myhost:5802/` . The applet will prompt you for your
>   password, and should then display the desktop.

Con:

- your password is [sent](http://lifehacker.com/287085/control-tightvnc-from-the-web) in plain text (HTTPS is not used). [RealVNC Viewer for Google Chrome](http://www.realvnc.com/products/chrome/) is much better in that respect (all communications are encrypted using 128-bit AES technology, so your connection cannot be intercepted or spied upon. For connections to Enterprise, ultra-secure 256-bit AES is available.).

Comment: Sending passwords plain-text via HTTP would be a no-go for sensitive environments. If I remember correctly, one could setup a connection via SSH with TightVNC (quite a while ago I've used it last); but I've no idea whether and how that would work for web-based access...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/):

- free
- supports Windows
- contains a [Web server](http://www.uvnc.com/features/javaviewer.html)

Comment: Same constraints as with TightVNC – or is it e.g. more secure? Sending passwords plain-text via HTTP would be a no-go for sensitive environments.